# Group table cells by decimal points

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Group the table cells based on the decimal points.**

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IazaxmIvd6X3PlMLs9Hm?p=preview)

**Sample JSON:**

```
[
    {
        "data1": [
            {
                "name": "Download",
                "id": "1.1.1"
            },
            {
                "name": "Download",
                "id": "1.1.2"
            },
            {
                "name": "Download",
                "id": "1.2"
            },
            {
                "name": "Download",
                "id": "1.3"
            },
            {
                "name": "Download",
                "id": "1.4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "data2": [
            {
                "name": "Download",
                "id": "2.1"
            },
            {
                "name": "Download",
                "id": "2.2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "data3": [
            {
                "name": "Download",
                "id": "3.1.1"
            },
            {
                "name": "Download",
                "id": "3.1.2"
            },
            {
                "name": "Download",
                "id": "3.2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "data4": [
            {
                "name": "Download",
                "id": "4.1.1"
            },
            {
                "name": "Download",
                "id": "4.1.2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

HTML:

```
<table border="0" class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody ng-repeat="(key,result) in results">
    <tr ng-repeat="r in result['data'+[key+1]]">
        <td rowspan="5">{{r.id}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

using **ng-repeat** to display each id in single cell of the table.

**Actual Result:**

[image]

**Expected Result**

[image]

Because of ng-repeat the cell are displaying next to each other. The expected result is to divide the table cell using the decimal points.

**Example:**

**Row1 =>** 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4

**Row2 =>** 2.1, 2.2

The Row2 first cell(2.1) should take the width of row1(1.1.1 and 1.1.2). And 2.2 should take the rest of the width of 1.2, 1.3 and 1.4

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should think about your data structure, maybe group the rows before, then in our template just have one ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

your data structure not clear, seems need to review and refactor it.
   but for now this plunker can help you. (i hope!)

```
link:
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2aSKkv1GtkVtGp2RoYeX?p=preview)